# mvc3 httpcontext in models

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, httpcontext

I currently reference HttpContext in my models. Is this good practice? Should I just pass in information I need instead?

For example, in my model code:

```
public void function()
{
 string param = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["param"];
 if(param == "myexpectations") { ...}
}

Should be changed to:

public void function(string param) //avoid hard reference this way??
{
 if(param == "myexpectations") { ...}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not good practice to reference `HttpContext` in your models.  You don't want that kind of tight coupling between your model and `HttpContext`.  It will make your model very difficult to test, among other things.  I would definitely go with your second option.

If you are retrieving your query string values in an action method, you don't need to use `HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString`.  You can allow ASP.NET's binding mechanism to bind the query string values to parameters in your action method.  E.g. If this is your URI:

```
http://localhost/Home/TestQueryString?param=ThisIsATestValue
```

Assuming you have your routes set up correctly, you can create your controller and action like this and MVC will bind the query string value `"ThisIsATestValue"` to the paramater `param`.

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult TestQueryString(string param)
    {
        string fromHttpContext = HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["param"];

        // result will be set to true
        bool result = param == fromHttpContext;
        return new EmptyResult();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, can you please explain and provide a link to MVC bind?

Comment: Sure, here is a great post explaining MVC model binding: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh781022.aspx. I won't explain more here since there is a lot to it. The example I gave is a very brief example of using the Querystring Value Provider (see the link for more info).

Comment: I would love to use the mvc framework binding http parameters to models (`public ActionResult TestQueryString(paramModel params)`) and use it in the controllers. But how to do this in a AuthorizeAttribute? The AuthorizeCore takes one argument and that is httpContext. I feel like programming a PHP web app in 1997 using this object. Yet examples showing how to access parameters show accessing raw httpcontext. Especially an array of strings would show up as a comma seperated string but the values also have comma's so no idea what is the seperator and the comma in the value anymore.